# Rails I18n attributes to fallback to default locale

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

We user I18n gem for translations in our application.

With the translations, it is expected to fallback to default_locale which is :en, if the translation is not available in corresponding locale.

```
Class Article
  ...
  translates :title
  ...
end
```

While accessing as a french user,

```
article.title => title in english 

but 

article.attributes(:title) => nil
```

I guess attributes picks directly from the active_record object (french translation) and since it is not available, it returns nil. Is there a way to make attributes as well fallback to default locale if translation is not available in corresponding locale.

Answer (score 1):

You can use I18n.fallbacks:

```
I18n.default_locale = :"en-US" 
I18n.fallbacks[:fr] # => [:fr, :"en-US", :en]
```

Take a look how to use Fallbacks on [I18n Wiki](https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n/wiki/Fallbacks)